# checking reference to a node object

Tags: reference, nodes

i have a question about this code.

```
class Queue {
    Node first, last
    void enqueue(Object item){
        if(!first){
            last = new Node(item);
            first = last;
        } else {
            last.next = new Node(item);
            last = last.next;
        }
    }
}
```

i guess im not really sure what exactly Node last is. When i write the line Node first, last, i heard i am making a reference to a node object. What exactly does that mean? Is it pointing to anywhere in memory? I know I never call the constructor so its not a new object. Could you give me some insight?

And what exactly does if(!first) mean? What is the if statement checking for since first is not a boolean? Thanks!

I would much appreciate clear and simple help. Thanks = )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Node first, last` line is declaring two variables of type Node.  One of them is named **first**, the second is named **last**.  These node objects are reference objects, because they contain the address to the data in memory, rather than containing the data itself.

More on reference vs value types: http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/value.htm

The line `last = new Node(item);` is actually calling the Node's constructor.  A new node is created, and it contains the item that was passed in.

`if(!first)` checks to see if the first node is empty.  If it is empty, then that code block is executed.  Otherwise the second block is executed.